# How long should character bios be for a TV treatment?

Tags: planning, scriptwriting

How long should character bios be for a TV treatment? 2-3 sentences? Or 2-3 paragraphs?

Comment: My favourite quote for questions like this is *"It should be like a miniskirt: long enough to cover the basics, but short enough to keep things interesting"*

Comment: That’s funny! I have trouble being succinct... so realistically the shorter the better... 2 paragraphs is probably a safe bet? I learn best from Ex... any link you can send where I can see a sample character bio? Thank you

Comment: @Chronocidal:  I use that frequently as my answer to "how long should this writing be."  Got it from a High School biology teacher of mine... and he was teaching at an all boy's school.  Know your audience indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you‘re creating a series bible I would expect an approx. half page about a main character and a paragraph about a minor character.
If you‘re promoting a tv movie, these would be even shorter. At the core I, as an editor, need to know:

- What are the (inner/outer) conflicts?
- Will these conflicts be sustainable for the duration of the movie?
- Is it an action-/character-driven drama?
- What is the character arc?
- Where does the character come from / where does it go to?
- What makes this character unique, special and interesting?

Just by looking at these questions you will see that „short“ depends on the complexity of the character you have created. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim any expertise in writing for TV, and I understand that your audience may *demand* a bio. Sigh. Still, I would write it when you finish the story, not before.

However, I think if you write the bio first, you will tend to cliche ("His father neglected him, so he's trying to get attention too much"). There's no simple Freudian explanation for how people act, and especially in real life, you don't know it anyway and you have to infer.

I'm curious what other writers think, but in my second book, I let the characters emerge via their actions and dialogue. I'd say it worked, in that at the end I really had the feeling that they were doing things on their own, as corny as that sounds.

Comment: So generally in television you will have more than one writer working on a series and they might right only a few of the episodes for the season.   Character bios are meant for the writers to have something they can know about the characters so that they don't write the perpetual underdog hero into a situation where he is grossly out of character.  Generally, this information is not meant for public disclosure and is kept in what's called the "series' Bible" which is a list of rules of the show's story for consistency.

Comment: +Sometime the bibles get published for public consumption after the fact... but often the bibles are largely disorganized messes of notes shared between the writers... if they exist at all.